# jq, re-assign field if it is a string with its parsed JSON representation

Tags: jq, fromjson

I have the following JSON:

```
[
{
    "test": "[\"example\"]"
},
{

    "test": ["example2"]
}
]
```

For each object, I want to 1] check if "test" is a string and 2] if test is a string, parse it into an actual JSON array and then re-assign it. So the output would be:

```
[
{
    "test": ["example"]
},
{

    "test": ["example2"]
}
]
```

I have tried the following code: `map(if .test|type == "string" then .test= .test|fromjson else . end)`. However, I get an error saying only strings can be parsed. I assume this is because jq thinks `.test` is not a string, but, I know .test is a string because of the if statement, so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jq filter can be simplified to:

```
map(if .test|type == "string" then .test |= fromjson else . end)
```

or even:

```
map(.test |= if type == "string" then fromjson else . end)
```

Comment: What does `|=` do? From my understanding `|` passes the value on the left into the value on the right.

Comment: See "Update-assignment: |=" in the jq manual (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be

`map(if .test|type == "string" then .test=(.test|fromjson) else . end)`

I'm guessing `.test=.test|fromjson` confused jq